# Вызов метода класса внутри класса

Tags: javascript

Как вызвать `w_2_test()` в `w_1_test()` ?

```
class TEST{

    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    //методы
    w_1_test(){
        w_2_test();
    }

    w_2_test(){
        console.log("LOG_ w_2_test()");
    }

}
```

Comment: this.w_2_test();

Comment: @Владимир Клыков точно. спасибо большое

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы получать доступ к методам класса внутри класса, нужно использовать ключевое слово **this**. То есть в вашей ситуации вызов будет выглядеть вот так:

```
w_1_test(){
    this.w_2_test();
}
```

Хотел бы порекомендовать вам хороший курс от Ильи Кантора https://learn.javascript.ru/es-class. Для новичков то что нужно!